# sas treatment of seed when generating random distributions

Tags: random, sas, random-seed

I needed to generate a poisson distribution in excel and found a method ([Inverse Transform Method](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4404-Sigman/4404-Notes-ITM.pdf))

did it in excel and then in sas (just for fun, so I do not need a quick answer) to compare with the `ranpoi` sas function.
Here my code (which works):

```
data Poisson(keep=mean Poisson PoissonSas);
mean=0.2;
confronta=exp(-mean);
do obs=1 to 100;
    found=0;
    Poisson=0;
    ranuni=1;
    do until(found=1);
        ranuni=ranuni*ranuni(12547);
        if ranuni<confronta then found=1;
        else Poisson=Poisson+1;
    end;
    PoissonSas=ranpoi(012584,mean);
    output;
end;
run;

proc means data=Poisson(drop=mean);run;
```

So I initialized the seed in both random functions to replicate results.
The strange thing is that I get different results depending on whether I submit the data step with both methods or only one of them (commenting the other), but the same results over and over for each type of submission. 
I expected the same results always! Why this is not so?
(I am using sas 9.3)
Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SAS is interleaving the calls to the PRNGs as a single stream.  Pseudo-random numbers are a sequence of values that are actually deterministic.  If you seed and use the sequence in one algorithm, you'll get the same results every time for that algorithm.  If you use the sequence alternating between two or more algorithms, the set of algorithms will always yield the same set of results (which seems to be the case for you), but the results for a given algorithm will be different because some of the underlying PRNs it was drawing before are now being used by the other algorithms.  This is at the core of the synchronization requirement when using so-called variance reduction techniques based on [common random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction#Common_Random_Numbers_.28CRN.29). In general, if you want identical results the solution is to have multiple instances of your PRNG, one for each "source" of randomness in your program, and to seed the multiple sources independently of each other but identically across runs.  It looks like you tried to do this, but SAS doesn't behave the way you think it does.  According to [their documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001281561.htm#a001281562), it appears that they produce a single PRN stream based on the first seed entry in your code!  This is a subset of one of their examples:

```
/* This DATA step calls the RANUNI and the RANNOR functions */
/* and produces a single stream of random numbers based on  */
/* a seed value of 7.                                       */   
data d;
   d = ranuni (7); f = ' '; output;
   d = ranuni (8); f = ' '; output;
   d = rannor (9); f = 'n'; output;
   /* they actually have more... */
run;
```

By the way, your Poisson algorithm is not generally regarded as an inverse transform algorithm. Inversion is 1-to-1, i.e., a single input uniform produces a single random variable.  The loop you're performing is actually doing acceptance/rejection, and you use a variable number of uniforms to come up with each Poisson value.

Comment: Thank you! The Inverse Transform Method just refers to the article's title

Comment: Yup, I saw. Whoever wrote that was mis-using the terminology though.

Answer (score 0):

PJS's answer is essentially correct, but a few clarifications.

SAS does indeed use a single seed when you do it the way you did; all of what I'd call 'primitive' random functions work off of one PRNG stream, and only the first seed matters (and only matters the first time it's encountered).

However, RANPOI is a little different - probably because of how SAS creates poissons.  It's not made clear in the documentation, but it appears that it uses up *two* random numbers (not sure if it's always two, or just coincidence).  See the following test:

```
data test;
U=ranuni(7);
P=ranpoi(8,100);
put u= p=;
run;


data test2;
p=ranpoi(8,100);
u=ranuni(7);
put u= p=;
run;

data test3;
u=ranuni(8);
p=ranuni(7);
put u= p=;=
run;

data test4;
u=ranuni(7);
p=ranuni(8);
put u= p=;
run;

data test5;
do _t = 1 to 5;
 u=ranuni(8);
 put u=;
end;
run;
```

Now, in test4, we see the first two ranuni's when starting with seed 7, and indeed the first one matches the first one from test.  However, test3 has the first two starting with seed 8, and the second one does *not* match the one from test2!  test5 shows that in fact the *third* matches, meaning ranpoi in test2 used up 2 numbers from the stream.

In any event, if you want to change the seed midstream, you have two options.

One is to use `CALL RANPOI` (and `CALL RANUNI`), which allow you to store the seed in a variable.  Two is to use `RAND` function, which works with `CALL STREAMINIT` to set seeds whenever you want to.  The `RAND` function is considered 'better' than the more primitive `RANPOI` and such - it uses a better PRNG algorithm.